# How do I wait for RxJS Websocket to get response in Protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, rxjs

I have a simple login page object that fills out login info and clicks a button. On that click a service calls a websocket using the Observable `Observable.webSocket(url)`. Then once a websocket response is sent back we move forward by navigating to another route. The testing issue is that after running the `click()` it still takes a few ms till we get the authentication response. This means the next line runs before the websocket returns and the router has been redirected (kind of guessing here). I have tried things like `elem.click().then(function(){...})` and `browser.wait` but the only thing that seems to work is `setTimeout`

Is there a way I can test these UI side effects sort of websocket messages using protractor?

Comment: You say once you receive a response, you navigate to another route.  Can you just use that?  Combine `browser.wait()` with `getCurrentUrl()` and return when the url contains the new route

Comment: I can try that and see, I was also thinking about just mocking my websocket service but then I think I am getting away from a true E2E test.

Comment: Actually that worked pretty well if I did something like `browser.wait(function(){ return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(x){ x === "..."})})` but I am not sure I like that. What happens when I have a message that doesn't change the url or something.

Comment: In that case I would probably just wait for something new to be appended to the DOM.  If for some reason that's difficult to capture (i.e. your new page is very similar to your old page in terms of HTML), you could wait for the old one to disappear (use Expected Conditions, `stalenessOf(...)`), and wait for the new one to appear (expected conditions, `presenceOf(...)`)

Answer (score 1):

As single-place solution: You can write your own predicate function for `browser.wait` that will execute JS on browser side and return true if socket is closed (or your own check):

```
let waitForWebSocket = () => {
    let jsFunction = () => {//some js code that will be executed on browser side
        //pseudocode. I beleive this will be something with promises and event listeners
        if (webSocketConnectionClosed) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return browser.executeScript(jsFunction)    
}

browser.wait(waitForWebSocket, 10000, 'WebSocket connection expected to be closed')
```

As a long term global solution for your test project. I would suggest to look into Protractor Plugins feature. You might define your own `waitForPromise` hook, that will be executed between every action.

http://www.protractortest.org/#/plugins

```
/**
 * Between every webdriver action, Protractor calls browser.waitForAngular() to
 * make sure that Angular has no outstanding $http or $timeout calls.
 * You can use waitForPromise() to have Protractor additionally wait for your
 * custom promise to be resolved inside of browser.waitForAngular().
 *
 * @this {Object} bound to module.exports
 *
 * @throws {*} If this function throws an error, a failed assertion is added to
 *     the test results.
 *
 * @return {q.Promise=} Can return a promise, in which case protractor will wait
 *     for the promise to resolve before continuing.  If the promise is
 *     rejected, a failed assertion is added to the test results, and protractor
 *     will continue onto the next command.  If nothing is returned or something
 *     other than a promise is returned, protractor will continue onto the next
 *     command.
 */
exports.waitForPromise = function() {};
```

And similar:

```
exports.waitForCondition
```

Comment: I think you might be on to something, however, as the fact I am using Protractor might imply I am working in Angular 2. So I am not sure what I would put in the pseudo code to access the ness. services. Also we are keeping the websocket open for push notifications. I think what might work like you describe if I can somehow grab ahold of the WS service I am using and grab the observable subject. I am just really not sure how to do this.